# Multiple balloons floating on strings

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, soft-body

I have a scene with multiple balloon text shapes, each on a string, like so:

[image]

What I'd like is to make each one bob up and down a little as if they are pulling against their strings, and ideally react to each other's motion, but I'm not sure how to achieve this. I read [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102240/balloon-simulation-string-is-floating-like-balloon) about making two separate sims, one for the string and another for the balloon, but I can't think how this would work with multiple balloons interacting together.

Any help much appreciated!

Andy (:

Comment: Can't you make several strings and an individual object for each letter? Add a *Cloth* (or *Softbody*) and  *Collision* modifier to each letter...

Comment: The only thing unrealistic is that the cord has no tension on it when the balloon pulls up. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDK97.gif

Comment: Each one is already an individual object, I'm just not sure how to get them to interact with a combination of cloth and rigid body physics. I should have some more time next week, so I'll experiment and post progress here.